# How to prevent a function call if the same arguments are passed?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I am trying to prevent the calculation inside of complexFunction in case same arguments are passed.

```
const complexFunction = (arg1, arg2) => { 
  /* complex calculation in here */ 
  console.log('complexFunction');
  return true;
};

// this is the method we need to implement
const memo=()=>{

}

const memoComplex = memo(complexFunction);

memoComplex(1, 2); // complex function should be executed   
memoComplex(1, 2); // complex function should not be invoked again, instead the cached result should be returned
memoComplex(1, 3); // complex function should be executed
```

Comment: I'm guess you got downvote for super generic good googling question, but anyways, if you still need an answer just use (_.memoize)[https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#memoize] from lodash

Comment: You need to show an approach solving that problem and explain what problem you have with that approach. Or if it works you could also ask if there another technique to solve that in a cleaner way.

Comment: One way is to have static variables in the function body to retain inputs and return value . Static variables are saved between function call.

Comment: So create an object. Use the arguments as a key. Check to see if the key exists in the object. If it does, return the value. If it does not run the code, store the result in the object, return the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an array of objects which holds the arguments to check if they've been used before, the code below demonstrates the use

```js
const usedArgs = [];
const memoComplex = (arg1, arg2) => {
    
    /* complex calculation in here */
    const value = arg1 + arg2;
    usedArgs.push({ arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2, data: value });
    return value;
};

const memo = (arg1, arg2) => {
    const exists = usedArgs.find(x => x.arg1 == arg1 && x.arg2 == arg2);
    if (exists) {
        console.log('loading from cache')
        return exists.data;
    } else return memoComplex(arg1, arg2);
}



console.log(memo(1, 2)); // complex function should be executed   
console.log(memo(1, 2)); // complex function should not be invoked again, instead the cached result should be returned
console.log(memo(1, 3)); // complex function should be executed
```

Comment: the idea is to implement this with the memo function

Comment: i don't actually understand what you're trying to do but i improved my answer try running the snippet

Answer (score -1):

You could save the arguments passed and the result in [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and on method call, look if you have already saved that in the storage, if that the case you could get it and return the result. Otherwise you would execute your method as always

```
sessionStorage.setItem('clé', 'valeur');
const complexFunction = (arg1, arg2) => { 
    // Get item return null if not found
    let potentialResult = sessionStorage.getItem("#1" + arg1.toString() + "#2" + arg2.toString());
    if(potentialResult !== null) {
        // If we have a result in session storage, that mean we have already done the calc
        // so we return the result
        return potentialResult;
    } else {
      // If we don't have a result, we just execute the function and save the result
      /* complex calculation in here */
      let result = "Your result"; // Assuming result is the result of your function
      // We save the result to avoid future calculation
      sessionStorage.setItem("#1" + arg1.toString() + "#2" + arg2.toString(), result);
      console.log('complexFunction');
      return true;
    }
};
```

But as said in the comments, this is more **a hint than a solution**, so please **adapt it to your use case**

Comment: There are multiple problems with your solution, but let me ask you: don't you think `foo(1, 23)` and `foo(12, 3)` are different calls?

Comment: Yeah, after thinking a little, that might be not a great idea :), what are the others problems ?

Comment: The other problems is that you use session storage, something that's not really fit for the purpose, for what is essentially computation "keys" (values you use to find computation results fast instead of calculating them). If you want serialization, you can use `JSON.stringify` instead, but serialization would be somewhat ill-fit to this class of problems -- it's neither required nor ideally suitable.